# how do i loop through sql results to populate a pdf using itextsharp

Tags: c#, sql-server, pdf, itext

I am trying to use iTextSharp to populate a [PDF](https://www.dropbox.com/s/j9m9dijbinyjfeh/f1095c.pdf?dl=0) from multiple SQL queries.
To fill out part 1 of the form, the query returns 1 name, for the second part, I need to loop through my results, which is where I am having a bit of trouble.

```
        using (var connection2 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=PUMA; Initial Catalog=CACTUS; User ID=somethinguser; Password=digital; Connection Timeout=50"))
        {
            using (var command2 = connection2.CreateCommand())
            {
                command2.CommandText = "SELECT * from MikeACATest WHERE SSN = " + SSN + "and RELATIONCODE <> '01'";
                connection2.Open();

                using (var reader2 = command2.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader2.Read())
                    {
                        var dNAME = reader2.GetValue(reader2.GetOrdinal("NAME"));
                        var dDOB = reader2.GetValue(reader2.GetOrdinal("DOB"));
                        var dP2_16_ALL = reader2.GetValue(reader2.GetOrdinal("P2_16_ALL"));
                        var dP2_16_1 = reader2.GetValue(reader2.GetOrdinal("P2_16_1"));
                        var dP2_16_2 = reader2.GetValue(reader2.GetOrdinal("P2_16_2"));
                        var dP2_16_3 = reader2.GetValue(reader2.GetOrdinal("P2_16_3"));
                        var dP2_16_4 = reader2.GetValue(reader2.GetOrdinal("P2_16_4"));
                        var dP2_16_5 = reader2.GetValue(reader2.GetOrdinal("P2_16_5"));
                        var dP2_16_6 = reader2.GetValue(reader2.GetOrdinal("P2_16_6"));
                        var dP2_16_7 = reader2.GetValue(reader2.GetOrdinal("P2_16_7"));
                        var dP2_16_8 = reader2.GetValue(reader2.GetOrdinal("P2_16_8"));
                        var dP2_16_9 = reader2.GetValue(reader2.GetOrdinal("P2_16_9"));
                        var dP2_16_10 = reader2.GetValue(reader2.GetOrdinal("P2_16_10"));
                        var dP2_16_11 = reader2.GetValue(reader2.GetOrdinal("P2_16_11"));
                        var dP2_16_12 = reader2.GetValue(reader2.GetOrdinal("P2_16_12"));

                        for (int i = 17; i < Convert.ToInt32(3) + 17; i++)
                        { //pdfFormFields declared earlier
                            pdfFormFields.SetField("Part[3]." + i + "a.CoveredUserName", dNAME.ToString());
                            pdfFormFields.SetField("Part[3]." + i + "c.CoveredUserDOB", dDOB.ToString());
                            pdfFormFields.SetField("Part[3]." + i + "d.cb.CoveredMonths[All]", dP2_16_ALL.ToString());
                            pdfFormFields.SetField("Part[3]." + i + "e.cb.CoveredMonths[Jan]", dP2_16_1.ToString());
                            pdfFormFields.SetField("Part[3]." + i + "e.cb.CoveredMonths[Feb]", dP2_16_2.ToString());
                            pdfFormFields.SetField("Part[3]." + i + "e.cb.CoveredMonths[Mar]", dP2_16_3.ToString());
                            pdfFormFields.SetField("Part[3]." + i + "e.cb.CoveredMonths[Apr]", dP2_16_4.ToString());
                            pdfFormFields.SetField("Part[3]." + i + "e.cb.CoveredMonths[May]", dP2_16_5.ToString());
                            pdfFormFields.SetField("Part[3]." + i + "e.cb.CoveredMonths[June]", dP2_16_6.ToString());
                            pdfFormFields.SetField("Part[3]." + i + "e.cb.CoveredMonths[July]", dP2_16_7.ToString());
                            pdfFormFields.SetField("Part[3]." + i + "e.cb.CoveredMonths[Aug]", dP2_16_8.ToString());
                            pdfFormFields.SetField("Part[3]." + i + "e.cb.CoveredMonths[Sept]", dP2_16_9.ToString());
                            pdfFormFields.SetField("Part[3]." + i + "e.cb.CoveredMonths[Oct]", dP2_16_10.ToString());
                            pdfFormFields.SetField("Part[3]." + i + "e.cb.CoveredMonths[Nov]", dP2_16_11.ToString());
                            pdfFormFields.SetField("Part[3]." + i + "e.cb.CoveredMonths[Dec]", dP2_16_12.ToString());
                            reader2.NextResult();
                        }
                    }
                }
                connection2.Close();
            }
        }
        pdfStamper.FormFlattening = false;
        pdfStamper.Close();
    }
```

The problem with this code is the command query `"SELECT * from MikeACATest WHERE SSN = " + SSN + "and RELATIONCODE <> '01'";` returns 3 names: Debra, Parker and Sarah.

What I need to do is get a count of how many names show up and loop through each name, populating the PDF. I know how to populate the PDF, but my issue is looping through the query.

In my for loop (which doesn't work btw), I hardcoded the number 3 and all 3 names were of the wife (https://i.stack.imgur.com/g28LJ.jpg).

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it to work

`reader2.NextResult();` was causing the issue because this was meant for multiple search queries at once like `select * from groupA; select....`